# Google Script returning full timezone information from a Google Sheet cell - how to stop it?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

My project is using Google Sheets to create a register system for childcare in a school. Because of the sensitive information within the document, I'm not at liberty to share access to the project.

'Week 1' has been decided as starting on 31/08/2020; subsequent weeks being calculated from that value.  So, Week 10's starting date would be (( [10-1] * 7 ) + 31/08/2020 ). This works fine.

This is how I'm returning the cell value in my script:

`var date = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();`

But when I return that cell value (in this instance, 14/09/2020) in my google script function, it is comes back like this: 'Sun Sep 13 2020 19:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time').  Why is this happening and how can it be resolved?  I presume it's something to do with cell formatting - the cell is currently set to automatic, but changing it to other date formats doesn't have any effect on the outcome.

All I want my script to do is to return the value **as displayed** in the Google Sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: To get a value as it's shown in a cell, instead of `getValue()` use `getDisplayValue()`.

---

You should be aware that `getValue()` / `getValues()` return a JavaScript Date object for cells containing a Date, Date-Time, Time, Duration Google Sheets values.

If you are seeing something like `Sun Sep 13 2020 19:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` is because the tool that you are using is parsing the JavaScript Date object as a string for displaying purposes.

Resources

- [Extending Google Sheets with Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)